# constrain general solution of ill-posed linear system to $\Re_+$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polyhedra, svd

I have a solution space of an under-determined linear system Ax = b with n x m matrix A:

$$x= x0 + V2 * c         (1)$$

with 
[U, S, V] = svd(A); 
V2 = V(:,r+1:end); 
$x0 = A^+ b; $
r = rank(A);

I need only non-negative solutions for x, so I want to intersect K-dim manifold defined in (1) with the positive m-space, $R^m_+$. As an intersection of convex sets - if it exists - it is convex too and is a finite convex K-Dim polyhedron in m-space. Currently I derive the vertices of this polyhedron by solving

```
Loop over all Idx = combinations 1:k out of 1:m
c=V2(Idx,:)\-x0(Idx);
vertex=x0+V2*c
accept vertex if ~any(vertex<0)
```

This loop is slow as there are the number of combinations is large and I need a faster method for finding this intersection and was wondering if there are more direct approaches for interection the solution manifold with $R^m_+$?

Comment: You surely have heard about "linear programming" (Matlab primitive "linprog"), which takes into account inequality constraints ? It's very efficient... even with hundred or thousand variables...

Comment: Yes done that but that only gets me a single "optimal" solution given my favorite cost function of the day. I am after the solution space to descibe uncertainty and so i can sample and update using a data assimilation approach.